# VB Exception ex.Message

Tags: vb.net

In c++ the ex.what() function gives me the exact message I wrote when I throw the exception, but in VB when I throw an exception with a custom message and use ex.Message, I get the original message of the exception in addition to mine.

Is there a simple way to only display my custom message?

example:

```
Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid Range")

    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException 'invalid range

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Message output is:

[image]

Instead of just "Invalid Range"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` the first parameter in the constructor is `ParamName` not `Message`. As this exception is used to indicate when an argument is out of range and `ParamName` to show which parameter that was.
Example:

```
Sub MySub(range As Integer)
    Try
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(Nameof(range), "Invalid Range")
    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If you just want to specify `Message` you need to write:

```
Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nothing, "Invalid Range")
```

Comment: `Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nothing, "Invalid Range")` 'Short and Sweet'. Nice one.